# How to find common address between certain tokens?

Tags: tokens

How do I find a common address between let's say COIN 1, COIN 2 or COIN 3 sellers and buyers? searching through Etherscan or similar explorer site can take hours and hours.

Any tool where we can put token contract addresses list and it scans for common address who have held or still actively holding those tokens?